# How to get the source of an non-source based module in python?

Tags: python, math

Since in Python 3.8 you can use `math.gcd` for more than two numbers and making it different from `fractions.gcd`, how can I see the source code for that function? Python IDLE says not a source-based module and I can't open it.

Comment: I believe this is the code you're looking for: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mathmodule.c#L831

Comment: To follow up on the comment from @Roy2012 the code in the math module ultimately invokes the function `_PyLong_GCD` whose source is https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L4709 . The code itself would require a large amount of effort to fully understand since you would have to first understand how Python's ints are implemented, but it is ultimately the Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: It uses the identity: gcd(a, b, c) = gcd(gcd(a, b), c). It has a shortcut based on the identity: gcd(1, a, b, c, ...) = 1.